# Adapter deployment failed IBM Worklight 6.0

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

```
Console View:
[2014-01-22 21:53:47]             Starting adapter deployment on Worklight Server
[2014-01-22 21:53:47]             Starting build of adapter: trial
 [2014-01-22 21:53:47]             Adapter deployment failed: Failed updating platform         version in adapter XML file     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\AdapterBuilderTask34474\trial.xml




trial.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
 5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
    disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<wl:adapter name="trial"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
xmlns:sql="http://www.worklight.com/integration/sql">

<displayName>trial</displayName>
<description>trial</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
        <!-- Example for using a JNDI data source, replace with actual data source name -->
    <!-- <dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName> --   >

        <!-- Example for using MySQL connector, do not forget to put the MySQL connector library in the project's lib folder -->
        <dataSourceDefinition>
            <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/IBM</url>
            <user>root</user>
            <password>root</password>
        </dataSourceDefinition>
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="5" />
</connectivity>

<!-- Replace this with appropriate procedures -->


<procedure name="procedure1"/>


<procedure name="procedure2"/>
</wl:adapter>
```

**trial-impl.js**

```
/*
 *  Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
 *  5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
 *  US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
 *  disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
 */

/************************************************************************
 * Implementation code for procedure - 'procedure1'
 *
 *
 * @return - invocationResult
 */

var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select COLUMN1, COLUMN2 from TABLE1 where COLUMN3 = ?");
function procedure1(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : [param]
    });
}

/************************************************************************
 * Implementation code for procedure - 'procedure2'



*
 *
 * @return - invocationResult
 */

function procedure2(param) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "storedProcedure2",
        parameters : [param]
    });
}
```

I am new to worklight studio. I Created a new Sql adapter and added the Jar connector        file to the bin folder of the project.
I made the necessary alterations in trial.xml file. Deploying the adapter resulted in errors.
I made a brief research about adapters but no solutions as of yet. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does it happen on every build & deploy? Do you have special read or write permissions on C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: No special permissions, and it does happen everytime I deploy it.

Comment: Could you confirm that you have actually copied the connector jar file into the **server/lib** folder rather than the **bin** one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided the XML declaration seems fine, the only thing that seems to be off is the location where you are copying the JDBC connector driver.

According to the Getting Started module ["SQL Adapter - Communicating with SQL database"](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf):

> The JDBC connector driver for the specific database type must be downloaded separately by the developer and added to the **server/lib/** folder of a Worklight project.

Please provide a copy of the adapter JavaScript file, which will allow the community to do a complete analysis of what could be wrong.